# How to extract chosen character from string in swift [Archived]

Tags: swift

I don't know how to extract a character, a word from a string in SWIFT.
I'd appreciate if someone could answer my question.

```
var Sth:String = "ABCDEF"
```

How do I extract only A or B or C

Edited 2/22/2021: I appreciate all of the answer, please do not attempt answering this further

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I meant: Ex: var Sth:String then how to extract a character from Sth

Comment: Add some example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension String {
  func index(from: Int) -> Index {
      return self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
  }

  func substringtx(with r: Range<Int>) -> String {
      let startIndex = index(from: r.lowerBound)
      let endIndex = index(from: r.upperBound)
      return substring(with: startIndex..<endIndex)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
var str:String = "ABCDEF"
print(str.substringtx(with: 0..<1)) //prints 'A'
print(str.substringtx(with: 1..<2)) //prints 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks but I got this error. Declaration is only valid at file scope at the UI view controller

Comment: put it on the out of your uiviewcontroller. Like: class ViewController: UIViewController {}
extension name: type {},   and do not forget the index function.

Comment: Why the declaration of the view controller? Doesn't seem to contribute to the solution.

Comment: Because he got an error, it was just as an example. But I removed it, you are right.